# On Submit Select next record of a model in yii

Tags: php, yii, model

I have to create a form. This form's content depends on a model I have to select. On submit, I have to save the user input and select the next record of the dependant model and then show another form.

The controller action :

```
public function actionAddInfo($id){
    $model1 = new DonneeComplement;
    $Valeur = new ValeurFournie;
    $participant = Participant::model()->find('id_participant = ' . $id);

    $info = InfoComplementAAjouter::model()->find('id_evenement = ' . $participant->id_evenement);

    //Here I might save the submitted data and and find the next $info in the records
    render('addInfo', array('model' => $model1, 'valeur' => $Valeur, 'info' => $info));
}
```

Can somebody help me to catch my problem ?

Comment: change `render('addInfo'` to **$this->render('addInfo'**

Comment: Thanks @Letmesee, it an error I made when typing. The problem remains.